# User is not in the allowed roles when pulling M365 signinactivity data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have a few customers whom we need to pull in display name and signinactivity for:

Using the auditlog permission and directory.read.all I am attempting to test that I can pull in the signinactivity data using the graph Api explorer.

Keep in mind that we're using Microsoft Entra ID Premium.

However, I am getting this error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Authentication_RequestFromUnsupportedUserRole",
    "message": "User is not in the allowed roles",
```

Also here is what my scope looks like in the token:

> "scp": "APIConnectors.Read.All AuditLog.Read.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All OnlineMeetingArtifact.Read.All OnlineMeetings.Read openid profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All email"

Any reason what the role needed for pulling the signinactivity is?

Here is the user roles: [image]

and app permissions: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To fetch the sign-in activity of the user `AuditLog.Read.All` and `Directory.Read.All` API permissions are required. One of the role must be assigned to the user as per this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

I assigned the user Active assignment **`Global Reader`** role:

[image]

I consented the API permissions and able to **successfully fetch the sign-in logs:**

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

[image]

If you are making use of Azure AD Application, make sure to **grant Admin consent to the API permissions**:

[image]

For **sample**, I generated access token by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to fetch the sign-in details of the user**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists,*** make sure you are using either work or school account or Service principal for authentication as personal Microsoft account is not supported.

- Make sure that you are signing in with the user with required roles to perform the action.

**Reference:**

[Permissions to extract SignInActivity from MS Graph - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad/permissions-to-extract-signinactivity-from-ms-graph/m-p/2193636) by Thomas Birk

Comment: So, the issue was that our admin set up permissions for this but without concern for the difference between eligible and active assignment. So needed to point out that I need the assignment to be activated.